# java ee - JSF 2.0 ViewScoped Bean after redirect to new window NPE

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I use tip from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/13838907 to open new tab, however when I go back to old one I get nullPointerException and my ViewScoped bean data are lost.

```
<h:form target="_blank">
  <p:commandButton value="open new tab" action="#{otherBean.newTab}" ajax="false" />
</h:form>

<h:form>
  <p:commandButton value="this wll cause NPE" action="#{pageBean.action}"/>
</h:form>
```

Click first button, go back to previous tab, click second button. PageBean is created once again and all data are lost. Both beans are ViewScoped.

Comment: The server does not know if you are opening the page in a new window or the same, so it interprets that your view has changed when opening the new page. Posted as comment because I do not know how you can workaround it (other than making the offending bean `@SessionScoped`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the view scoped bean in the initial tab/window get killed by returning a `String` navigation case outcome. You would like to return `null` or `void` to keep it alive. Based on the `newTab()` code as shown in your other question, you need to replace the navigation case by a [`Faces#redirect()`](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/current/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) call (assuming that it's indeed [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) which you're using there for `Faces#setFlashAttribute()`). You only need to set `Flash#setRedirect()` to `true` beforehand to instruct the flash scope that a redirect will occur.

```
public void newTab() throws IOException {
    Faces.setFlashAttribute("foo", bar); 
    Faces.getFlash().setRedirect(true);
    Faces.redirect("otherView.xhtml");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it's fully working. However I must use void action method - returning null causes redirect open in the same tab

Comment: Thanks. But how to do it without OmniFaces?

Answer (score 1):

ViewScope beans only live as long as you post back to same view.

If you post back to other views in your `action` data will be lost since the ViewScope bean will be recreated.