# p:commandLink fails to open page in new window/tab

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, commandlink

I'm trying to create a link to open a new page in a different window/tab and display some msg from backing bean but fail to do it, wonder know why?

here is my xhtml file:

```
<html:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h:body>
    <h:form id="form66">
    <p:commandLink actionListener="#{testing.getMessage}" action="msg.xhtml" target="_blank">get Msg</p:commandLink>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

here is my Msg.xhtml page

```
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <h:head>
    <title>testing</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
    <div class="div">
      <p:panel>
        <f:facet name="header">
          testing
        </f:facet>
        <div class="paddingForPanel">
          <h:outputText value="#{testing.msg}" escape="false"/>             
        </div>
      </p:panel>            
    </div>
  </h:body>
</HTML>
```

here is my testing.java

```
public void getMessage() {      
    this.msg = "haha";
}

private String msg;
public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}
public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}
```

the code above fail to open a new tab/window, I try to do like below, it success to open the new page in new tab but the msg is empty, when I debug, it got success call the listenner getMessage, I wonder know why the msg is empty in the msg.xhtml page?
Thanks in advance....

```
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{testing.getMessage}" oncomplete="window.open('msg.xhtml')">broadcast Msg</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: Try to set `ajax="false"` in the first version of your `commandLink`.

Comment: What is your Bean scope ?

Comment: @heng heng  **[Hope this is helpfull](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865710/when-i-click-on-any-link-it-should-open-in-the-same-new-window-in-jsf-primeface/20875521#comment31361077_20875521)**

Answer (score 19):

`<p:commandLink>` has some ajax issues, Use  `<h:commandLink>`  instead.

```
 <h:commandLink actionListener="#{testing.printMessage}" action="/Msg.html" target="_blank">get Msg</h:commandLink>
```

changed `<p:commandLink>` to `<h:commandLink>` and your code is working fine.

Comment: *"some ajax issues"* How's that an answer? Your solution is right, but you're explaining it completely wrong.

Comment: yes I agree. I just gave a workaround. I should have posted it as comment.

Comment: And yet, this is by far the best answer. I'll take "some ajax issues".

Comment: with `<p:commandLink>`, you can make it work by having attribute `ajax=false`

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉: Which PF version? Since your statement contradicts the other answer

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉: Please check. It if so, we nee to add this explicitly to this answer and to the other 5 upvoted one.

Answer (score 6):

Both are not working so issue is not in primefaces ajax. Issue in target attribute of p:commandLink its not working...

```
<p:commandLink value="New Window" ajax="false" target="_blank" action="test"/>

<p:commandLink value="New Window" target="_blank" action="test"/>
```

SO we have to use

```
<h:commandLink value="New Window" target="_blank" action="test"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

I do it like this:

```
<p:commandLink id="link" actionListener="#{testing.getMessage}" 
    oncomplete="popupwindow('msg.xhtml', 'newwindow');" >  
    <h:outputText value="broadcast Msg" />
</p:commandLink>
```

With some javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
function popupwindow(url, title) {      
    window.open(url , title, "toolbar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=170, left=170, width=800, height=600");        
}    
</script>
```

In this example you open a new window, hope its helps!

Answer (score 1):

### If you are using remotecommand then you can do like this

```
<p:remoteCommand name="lookAndBookNewTab"
     process="@this" action="#{lookAndBookMB.onPageLoadForNewTab()}"
     rendered="#currentUserManager.
     hasPermission('LookAndBook','View')}"             update=":messageForm:growl" />
```

And my javascript:

```
<script> 
    if(event.ctrlKey &amp;&amp; event.shiftKey &amp;&amp; event.keyCode == 119) {
     lookAndBookNewTab(); 
    event.preventDefault();
</script>
```

---

ServerSide action method:

```
public String onPageLoadForNewTab(){
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest(); String url = req.getRequestURL().toString();
        url=(url.substring(0, url.length() - req.getRequestURI().length()) + req.getContextPath() + "/"); url=url+navigationpagename+".jsf"; RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().
        execute("window.open('"+url+"','_blank')");** 
    return ""; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller code, it worked for me perfectly.

```
HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            String uri = req.getRequestURI();
            res.getWriter().println("<script>window.open('" + myUrl + "','_blank', 'location=yes,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=yes,status=yes'); window.parent.location.href= '"+uri+"';</script>");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is wondering about it, using Primefaces 9,10,11 doing this

```
<p:commandLink value="New Window" ajax="false" target="_blank" action="test"/>
```

does work in case you do not want to use h:commandLink

Answer (score -1):

like this,

```
<h:link target="_blank" value="Other page" outcome="your url"></h:link>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Please add some text and explanation to your answer.

Answer (score -2):

like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN'
     'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>

     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


    <h:head>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="base" name='jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css' />
    </h:head>
    <span style="background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);">
      <h:form target="_blank">
        <p:commandButton value="Run" action="#{bean.createReport}"  />
      </h:form>
    </span>
    </html>
```

see:[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146940/jsf-target-blank-not-working-with-primefaces-commandbutton)

Comment: Why in earth is this non-working answer (`ajax="false"` is completely missing), flavored with a completely irrelevant `<span>` and potentially conflicting jquery-ui library (PrimeFaces ships with its own), upvoted? Are there *still* blind monkeys in /review?