# When i click on any link it should Open in the same New Window in JSF, Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

In my JSF page i have few `Links{link1,link2,link3,link4}-{Student Id's}.`

What i tried is when i click on the Link it Opens the Student-Information in a `"NEW WINDOW".`

When i am clicking on the next Link it is Opening a New Window,but i want to open in the Same New Window i.e., the TARGET should be the Same NEW Window which is opened.

**Diagramatical Representation:**

[image: Target Link to Same Window]

My Piece of Code which i had tried from collecting things from STACKOVERFLOW[Open Page in New Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724518/jsf2-primefaces-pcommandlink-open-page-in-new-window-tab) :

```
<p:dataTable id="studentDtTble" var="studData" value="#{studentController.dataList}">
        <p:columnGroup type="header">
            <p:row>
                    <p:column headerText="StudentId"></p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="StudentName"></p:column> 
                    <p:column headerText="Add" ></p:column>     
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>
            <p:column>
                <p:commandLink id="sidlink" action="/studentinfo.xhtml" target="_blank">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{studData.studentId}" styleClass="txtlink" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
               <h:outputText value="#{studData.studentName}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column >
                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{studData.add}" />
            </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
```

Edited After @Nosnhoj Reply :`When i Click on any of the SID Link then there Details Should Opened in the "Same NEW Window".`

Comment: @Makky i had pasted a sample code hope it may help.As, i am new to JSF, Primefaces.i'm unable to make it up. correct me if i am going wrong any where. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Did you try the answers in your previous questions?

Comment: Can you not use Dialog box instead of showing results in different tab ??

Comment: @Makky My Reqirement is that i have a Page of Student Information to be Displayed, So i want to Show them as a Separate Page. The Dialog Box is a good One which can be useful, but it is'nt the case i want to be..i added a comment for the answer Below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `<h:commandLink>` instead of `<p:commandLink>`.

I tried your code and make a little change like this:

```
<h:commandLink id="sidlink" action="#{studentController.selectStudent(studData)}" target="_blank">  
    <h:outputText value="#{studData.studentId}" styleClass="txtlink" />
</h:commandLink>
```

I **changed `<p:commandLink>` to `<h:commandLink>`**, and **call a method in the backing bean to set the selected Student**.(For the `New Window` should need the student information.)

Here is the code of `studentController.selectStudent` :

```
private Student selectedStu;

public String selectStudent(Student stu) {
    selectedStu = stu;
    return "/studentinfo.xhtml";
}
```

And the following is the code of `New Window`：

```
 <h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Another Link" action="/anotherinfo.xhtml" target="_self"/>
    <br/>
    Student: <h:outputText value="#{studentController.selectedStu.studentName}"/>
 </h:form>
```

Which is just showing name of the selected Student, and another link you want.
Note that the `target` attribute is `_self` because you want the new page show in the same window.

Finally, the `anotherinfo.xhtml` is just an empty page I created via NetBeans, so there's no need to post it.

And here's what you may see:
[image]

After clicking the id of "Johnson" :
[image]

After clicking "Another Link" :
[image]

---

### Update

As @User2561626 explain what he/she intended to, I update my answer as follow:
If you want a ***New Window*** pop up in stead of ***New Tab***, you should change the code like:

```
<p:commandLink id="sidlink" actionListener="#{studentController.selectStudent(studData)}" oncomplete="window.open('studentinfo.xhtml', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250');">  
    <h:outputText value="#{studData.studentId}" styleClass="txtlink" />
</p:commandLink>
```

I change `<h:commandLink>` back to `<p:commandLink>`, make `action` as `actionListener` because we want to set the selected Student first, finally I add `window.open` in `oncomplete` attribute so that the new page will open in a new window but not tab.
Of course we need to edit the method `studentController.selectStudent()`, like this:

```
public void selectStudent(Student stu) {
    selectedStu = stu;
}
```

As you can see, the return type is **void** now, and the only thing this method do is just set the selected Student.
Hope this may help.

Comment: The answer is good! It is working Fine. but, my requirement is that if we click on the sid Consider in your scenario u had clicked on sid:2 and then the "NEW WINDOW" had opened.then again if i click on sid:4 then the same "NEW WINDOW" should be Refreshed and display the StudentInfo.

Comment: Then just change `target="_blank"` to `target="_new"`.

Comment: how can it open in the Same window which is opened, then for every link i click it opens a NEW Window, there the old Window Remains Opened.

Comment: The `target="_new"` is working fine.but, i am surprised how can it open in the same Window.. It is opening a Window as a new "tab", can we make it open in a "New Window"

Comment: It Worked fine! but As on the Second Click it is not Focusing on the New Window. i tried with `window.open('studentinfo.xhtml', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250').focus();` it worked ! Thanks For your Support