# how to open page in new window NOT tab using h:commandLink?

Tags: jsf

Using Primefaces 4.0 and JSF 2.2.

I would like to send the visitor to a page in a new window (not tab). The landing page is a jsf page called `grade.xhtml`

I tried:

```
<h:commandLink value="OK" onclick="window.open('grade.html', 'newwindow','width=300, height=300'); return false;"/>
```

This gets to a 404. Obviously this is all happening client side so grade.html doesn't get generated from `grade.xhtml`. How should I do?

Note: if I put `onclick="window.open('grade.xhtml', 'newwindow','width=300, height=300'); return false;"` then the page does open, but it is the jsf (xhtml code) not html version that shows up.

Comment: use an absolute path for the URL?

Comment: still a 404 with /grade.html

Comment: Check your settings. @Tiago answer is correct. Plain html `<a href="#{request.contextPath}/privacy.html" target="_blank">#{msg.privacy}</a>` opens new window too. Both were retested.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<h:commandLink value="OK" action="grade.xhtml" target="_blank"/>
```

Look an example here: [When i click on any link it should Open in the same New Window in JSF, Primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865710/when-i-click-on-any-link-it-should-open-in-the-same-new-window-in-jsf-primeface)

Comment: @seinecle You are not correct. Code from this answer open new window. Check your settings.

Answer (score 2):

I use javaScript for this.. Try it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function funcForWindowPopup()
    {
        var popup = null;
        popup = window.open("grade.xhtml", "popup", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=no,left=350,top=50,width=650, height=600");
        popup.openerFormId = "formID";
        popup.focus();
    }

</script>
```

You can change parameters as you need;)

Comment: Thx! Still, this redirects to the jsf version of grade.xhtml (the one with all jsf tags), not the html version. I checked that the simple '<p:commandLink value="OK" action="grade.xhtml"/>' works fine. I can't see what's wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

Open the URL in new window from JSF controller.

```
HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            String uri = req.getRequestURI();
            res.getWriter().println("<script>window.open('" + myUrl + "','_blank', 'location=yes,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=yes,status=yes'); window.parent.location.href= '"+uri+"';</script>");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

Comment: window.parent.location.href= '"+uri+"'  this will refresh the parent page to bring it back.