# primefaces filedownload in childwindow

Tags: primefaces

i am having `p:filedownload` in a `primefaces` data table like this

```
<p:column>
        <p:commandLink id="downloadLink"
                                style="color:blue;text-decoration:underline; "
                                disabled="#{ShipAttach.deleteSelect}" onclick="trailNewpage();"
                                value="#{ShipAttach.bpmfilename}" ajax="false">
                                <p:fileDownload contentDisposition="inline"
                                    value="#{filedownloadController.fileDownload(ShipAttach)}" />
                            </p:commandLink>
                        </p:column>
```

when i click on the link i am getting the file opened in a same window ,i was also able to open the file in the new tab by specifying the attribute `target="_blank"` i want these file to be opened in Childwindow,please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to first open a new window via a plain link. In there load a page where you do an automatic click on the download button. Al so simple...

Comment: No actually the link is present in the data table ,For eg:if 10 rows are present ,if i want a file downloaded from first row i want to click in the first row and make the file content displayed in the child window

Comment: Same thing... Create a plain link that  does a 'get request'  (so not a commandLink) in a new window that contains parameters that point to the file to be downloaded...

Comment: @Kukeltje When target="_blank" opening of new tab or childwindow is governed by browser settings or not?

Comment: Yes, and I learned something tonight. According to the specs, `h:commandLink` supports target. Hmmmm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724518 `p:commandLink` does not

Answer (score 1):

I had quite the same problem with a commandLink opening a fileDownload in a newTab. I was forced to use setTimeout to make it work (but I don't understand why).

With the old code, the link opens the new tab with the same page, but not the fileDownload :

```
<h:commandLink
        onclick="doStuff()"
        target="_blank">
    <p:fileDownload contentDisposition="inline" value="#{myFile}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

With the new code, the link opens the new tab with the fileDownload :

```
<h:commandLink
        onclick="setTimeout(doStuff, 0)"
        target="_blank">
    <p:fileDownload contentDisposition="inline" value="#{myFile}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: What does your 'doStuff' do? What if you remove it? Does it work then?

Comment: Oh and this question is about the **PrimeFaces** `p:commandLink`, not the `h:commandLink`... So you answer won't help here. Maybe if you create a new question with your original code (in [mcve] flavour) we can see what was/is your problem and why your change worked for you